# Getting elements from an array from different class

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

I have class Maraton that looks like this:

```
public class Maraton implements IMaraton {
private Atleticar[] niza;
public Maraton(Atleticar[] niza) {
    super();
    this.niza = niza;
}
```

And i class Atleticar that looks like this:

```
public class Atleticar{

private double vreme;

public double getVreme() {
    return vreme;
}
public void setVreme(double vreme) {
    this.vreme = vreme;
}
```

And i want make function in Maraton that gives me back the shortest "vreme".
I have difficulties with implementing this method because i am new to java. Any advice would be appreciated. Tnx in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention, also in class Maraton i have `public Atleticar[] getNiza() {
  return niza;
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is rather simple : you have to iterate on the array to compute which element is the minimal.

But it seems to be a very good use case for functional programming :

```
OptionalDouble min = 
Arrays.stream(niza)
      .mapToDouble(Atleticar:getVreme)
      .min();
```

Then process the `OptionalDouble` state according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the array and find the shortest value of all.

```
double shortestVreme = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for(Atleticar arrElement: niza) {
   if(arrElement.getVreme() < shortestVreme) {
      shortestVreme = arrElement.getVreme();
   }
}
return shortestVreme; // from the method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public Atleticar getFastestOne(){
  Optional<Atleticar> optAtleticar = Arrays.stream(niza).min(Comparator.comparing(Atleticar::getVreme));
  if(optAtleticar.isPresent()){
     return optAtleticar.get();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public static int getMinVreme(int[] array) {
    int minValue = array[0].getVreme;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].getVreme < minValue) {
            minValue = array[i].getVreme;
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

should work for you.